# NGINX and OKTA configuration with localhost

Tags: nginx, localhost, okta

I have a problem configuring NGINX with Okta getting the 400 bad request page with the following messages: Identity Provider: Unknown Error Code: invalid_request Description: The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be an absolute URI that is whitelisted in the client app settings.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

In your address bar is the URL it's trying to go to. If you copy and paste it into a text editor, you should be able to read what redirect_uri it's trying to send. Take that value and put it into your OIDC app on Okta as a Login redirect URI. Then, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response I got this kind of url: https://cgroup-dev.oktapreview.com/oauth2/auso5fxh5zF8HWMmK0h7/v1/authorize?client_id=0oao5cxceeihfo3Zg0h7&nonce=vnwhe9NP9arqRz604r0Ppz1FIIFiMwkHverAzIvINIo1oLLyn9UQLNNArBlfGYJR&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3003%2Fimplicit%2Fcallback&response_mode=fragment&response_type=id_token%20token&state=C2fEqnHIwerDEAIEWWnGA5X3cqjqoai5STqUIUSDNfn0sO95ng2OuOzjjgUGbiRi&scope=openid%20email%20profile

Comment: It looks like you need to add `http://localhost:3003/implicit/callback` as a login redirect URI to your app.

Comment: I apreciate the help, I will try that .

Comment: Here is my settings: General Settings
Cancel
APPLICATION
Application label 
DMA
Application type Single Page App (SPA)
Allowed grant types 
Client acting on behalf of a user

Authorization Code

Implicit

Allow ID Token with implicit grant type

Allow Access Token with implicit grant type
LOGIN
Login redirect URIs 
Add URI
http://localhost:3003/implicit/callback
Logout redirect URIs 
Add URI
Login initiated by 
App Only
Initiate login URI 
http://localhost:3003/implicit/callback